# Comparing two rows at a time in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark

I am new to Spark, and am looking for help with best practices. I have a large DataFrame, and need feed two rows at a time into a function which compares them.

`actual_data` is a DataFrame with an `id` column, and several value columns.

`rows_to_compare` is a DataFrame with two columns: `left_id` and `right_id`.

For each pair in `rows_to_compare`, I'd like to feed the two corresponding rows from `actual_data` into a function.

My actual data is quite large (~30GB) and has many columns, so I've reduced it to this simpler example:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
import builtins

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
# Build DataFrame of Actual Data
data = { 
    'id': [1,2,3,4,5],
    'value': [11,12,13,14,15]}
actual_data_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    pd.DataFrame(data, columns=data.keys()))

# Build DataFrame of Rows To Compare
rows_to_compare = {
    'left_id': [1,2,3,4,5],
    'right_id': [1,1,1,1,1]}
rows_to_compare_df = 
    sqlContext.createDataFrame(
        pd.DataFrame(rows_to_compare, columns=rows_to_compare.keys()))

result = (
    rows_to_compare_df
        .join(
            actual_data_df.alias('a'),
            col('left_id') == col('a.id'))
        .join(
            actual_data_df.alias('b'),
            col('right_id') == col('b.id'))
        .withColumn(
            'total',
            builtins.sum(
                [col('a.value'), 
                 col('b.value')]))
        .select('a.id', 'b.id', 'total')
        .collect())
```

This returns the desired output:

`[Row(id=2, id=1, total=23), Row(id=5, id=1, total=26), Row(id=4, id=1, total=25), Row(id=1, id=1, total=22), Row(id=3, id=1, total=24)]`

When I run this, it seems quite slow, even for this toy problem. Is this the best way of approaching this problem? The clearest alternative approach I can think of is to make each row of my DataFrame contain the values for both rows I'd like to compare. I'm concerned about this approach though since it will involve a tremendous amount of data duplication.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.